# Dax Calculation and Table Creation

Tags: powerbi, dax

o I have this formula

```
L_RM = FILTER(L_BRT,(L_BRT[Due Date]>= DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-1,1,1)) && 
(L_BRT[Type] IN {"HR Training", "Issue-Remediation", "PDMS", "Policy Deviation","SoD User Account Access", "SoD Service Account Management", "SoD Entitlement Verification","Action Plan"})
&& (L_BRT[Mandatory/Required Training] IN {"Mandatory", BLANK()}))
```

And I am trying to make update to HR type to include only Items where official IT due date is Y, and also add some other types starting from this year 2024 :

```
Network Pentest Finding          
LCM Model - EOL 
LCM Model - Missing Attribute(s)
Security Baseline-Attestation
Security Baseline-Baseline Amendment
Security Baseline-Baseline Deviation
Security Baseline-Existing Baseline
MCT Exceptions
Compliance
```

and should include Required training starting from this year 2024

I have this formula but i am not getting the right value

```
L_RM = FILTER(L_BRT,(
    (L_BRT[Due Date] >= DATE(YEAR(TODAY()) - 1, 1, 1)
     && ( (L_BRT[Type] = "HR Training" && L_BRT[OfficialITDueDateRM] = "Y")
    || ( L_BRT[Type] IN { "Issue Remediation", "PDMS", "Policy Deviation", "SoD User Account Access", "SoD Service Account Management", "SoD Entitlement Verification", "Action Plan" }
    && L_BRT[Mandatory/Required Training] = "Mandatory"))
    || (( L_BRT[Mandatory/Required Training] = "Required" && L_BRT[Due Date] >= DATE(2024, 1, 1) )
    || ( L_BRT[Due Date] >= DATE(2024, 1, 1) && L_BRT[Type] IN {"Compliance", "Network Pentest Finding", "MCT Exceptions", "LCM Model - EOL", "LCM Model - Missing Attribute(s)", "Security Baseline-Attestation", "Security Baseline-Baseline Amendment", "Security Baseline- Baseline Deviation", "Security Baseline Existing Baseline" }
     )))))
```

As an alternative i created 2 tables using Dax and created a final table using union and distinct

when in the union table i get some wrong values for some items but in each single table before appending with union it is correct, Please help out , see formulae below

```
L_RM1 = FILTER(L_BRT,(L_BRT[Due Date]>= DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-1,1,1)) && ( (L_BRT[Type] = "HR Training" && L_BRT[OfficialITDueDateRM] = "Y")
    ||(L_BRT[Type] IN {"Issue-Remediation", "PDMS", "Policy Deviation","SoD User Account Access", "SoD Service Account Management", "SoD Entitlement Verification","Action Plan"}) && (L_BRT[Mandatory/Required Training] IN {"Mandatory", BLANK()})))
```

```
L_RM2 = FILTER(L_BRT,(L_BRT[Due Date]>=  DATE(2024, 1, 1) && (L_BRT[Type] IN {"Network Pentest Finding", "MCT Exceptions", "LCM Model - EOL", "LCM Model - Missing Attribute(s)", "Security Baseline-Attestation", "Security Baseline-Baseline Amendment", "Security Baseline- Baseline Deviation", "Security Baseline Existing Baseline", "Compliance"}) && (L_BRT[Mandatory/Required Training] IN {"Required", BLANK()})))
```

```
L_RM = DISTINCT (UNION (L_RM1, L_RM2))
```

Answer (score 0):

For your single, updated filter formula to include only items where the "Official IT Due Date" is "Y" for "HR Training" and to add the new types from 2024 with "Required" training :

```
L_RM = FILTER(
    L_BRT,
    (L_BRT[Due Date] >= DATE(YEAR(TODAY()) - 1, 1, 1) &&
        ((L_BRT[Type] = "HR Training" && L_BRT[OfficialITDueDateRM] = "Y") ||
        (L_BRT[Type] IN {"Issue-Remediation", "PDMS", "Policy Deviation", "SoD User Account Access", "SoD Service Account Management", "SoD Entitlement Verification", "Action Plan"} &&
         L_BRT[Mandatory/Required Training] = "Mandatory"))) ||
    ((L_BRT[Due Date] >= DATE(2024, 1, 1) &&
        L_BRT[Type] IN {"Network Pentest Finding", "LCM Model - EOL", "LCM Model - Missing Attribute(s)", "Security Baseline-Attestation", "Security Baseline-Baseline Amendment", "Security Baseline-Baseline Deviation", "Security Baseline-Existing Baseline", "MCT Exceptions", "Compliance"} &&
        L_BRT[Mandatory/Required Training] IN {"Required", BLANK()}))
)
```